# Port forwarding connection refused

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I've read all the previous similar questions but none of them is helping me. I have forwarded my ports through the page of the router however online websites like canyouseeme.org do not see my ports as opened. Canyouseeme.org says "connection refused". I have scanned my public up using nmap and it recognizes the port I want as opened. I have deactivated the firewall of the computer and the one on the routers page.

My router is Huawei HG8546M. Any idea what could the problem be?

Comment: The most likely case is you don't have a real public IP and are behind a Enterprise Grade NAT device... very common for residential service from ISP's. Everything incoming stops at the ISP's router as that is where the public IP address(es) reside. A simple test is remove your port forwarding and enable the routers web interface from the WAN/Public side and see if you can access the web page of the router from an external location like work or a coffee shop, if you can than the issue us your setup, if you can't it's likely blocked by your ISP.

Comment: Another test is look at the IP address in the router's status page, is it's WAN/Internet/Public address assigned by the ISP in private IP range space, or is it a truly public IP address? If it's in private IP space (10.0.0.0/24, 172.16.0.0/12, or 192.168.0.0/16) then you don't need to look any further, you do not have a public IP address and port forwarding will never work.